# Make xcodebuild -exportLocalizations know how to parse custom NSLocalizedString macro

Tags: xcode, localization, xcodebuild

Using the built in macro:

```
NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"fantasy-group.group-rank.stats-label", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle], @"Group Rank", nil);
```

Results in the following block in the resultant `.xliff` file when I export for localizations:

```
  <trans-unit id="fantasy-group.group-rank.stats-label">
    <source>Group Rank</source>
    <note>No comment provided by engineer.</note>
  </trans-unit>
```

This works as expected since [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000005-97055):

> The main advantage to these macros is that they can be parsed by the
>   `genstrings` tool and used to create your application’s strings files.

But if I try and get snazzy with my own macro to avoid specifying table and bundle, and possibly to specify my own table in an effort to [split up the string file](http://www.objc.io/issues/9-strings/string-localization/#splitting-up-the-string-file):

```
#define WSLLocalizedString(key, val, comment) \
[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:(val) table:nil]

[WSLLocalizedString(@"fantasy-group.group-rank.stats-label", @"Group Rank", nil);
```

It doesn't get picked up by XCode or the associated command line tool when I try to generate the xliff file:

```
$ xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath WSL/Translations/ -project WSL.xcodeproj
```

If I were just doing genstrings, I could do the following [source](http://www.objc.io/issues/9-strings/string-localization/):

```
find . -name *.m | xargs genstrings -o en.lproj -s WSLLocalizedString
```

But I want xliffs. Is there a param I can pass to `xcodebuild` to keep this dream alive?

Comment: I'm facing same issue.  It looks like it only looks for "NSLocalizedString" in your source code, and does not expand the search into macros.  I had to remove my macros and call NSLocalizedString directly.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Objective-C, but I have done this for Swift by redefining the `NSLocalizedString` function like that:

```
public func NSLocalizedString(key: String, tableName: String? = nil, bundle: NSBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: String = "", comment: String) -> String
{
    return yourBundleHere.localizedStringForKey(key, value: value, table: tableName)
}
```

In my case I was needed to use custom `NSBundle`.